# Jquery commands that i dont know how to use

Tags: jquery

This may seem a simple question but im trying to find my way trough the Jquery code and wanted to ask how you can get to know the list of commands that you can use to manipulate the Jquery commands.

For other codes it would also be handy if there is a list so you know what is possible for commands.

I searched the http://jquery.com/ website but could not find a list of commands like below for (this.checked) or opts.push(this.name).

So if i want to relace 'checked' for example how do I know what to put in there ?

```
function getEmployeeFilterOptions2(){
var opts = [];
$onchange.each(function(){
if(this.checked){
opts.push(this.name);
}
});
```

Comment: You'll need to learn javascript and/or jQuery. You can get an intro to jQuery at http://learn.jquery.com, but that kind of assumes you know some javascript already. As a side note, `this.checked` and `opts.push(this.name)` are pure javascript, there's no jQuery there.

Comment: Do you mean intellisense?

Comment: Also, _"how do I know what to put in there"_ - Well, if you only speak english, how do you know what french words you can use to build a sentence? You learn french.

Comment: Once you went through http://learn.jquery.com/, you already have a feeling of what functions jQuery has. You can also search for it on http://api.jquery.com/ first. If you don't find anything, it's either a different library, native JavaScript or the DOM API. I usually just do a Google search for `mdn <keyword>` to search for documentation on the MDN site. For example: [`mdn checked`](https://www.google.com/search?q=mdn+checked) and [`mdn push`](https://www.google.com/search?q=mdn+push). Of course you should know JavaScript basics to some degree. Read a tutorial!

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't find them in the jQuery site is because they are not jQuery features, they are native (and I must say very basic) Javascript and/or DOM features.

`this.checked` and `this.name` are just properties of a DOM element

`opts.push` is calling `Array.prototype.push` on the (array) variable named `opts`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the currently selected element within the `each` loop.

`this.checked` and `this.name` are native JavaScript properties assigned to the element currently selected.

`$.each` is a jQuery function documented here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

`opts = []` is assigning an array to the variable "opts".

`opts.push()` is pushing a value into the "opts" array (again, this is native JavaScript, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).